# Android Camera Intent fails to reach onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to make an activity in my application which consists of two buttons, "Take photo", which calls an intent to take a photo using the default camera, "Choose Existing", which calls an intent to pick a existing image from the gallery. As stated in many tutorials, one would require the use of the onActivityResult function. My application fails to reach that function (stuck at the camera after taking photo, pressing the tick doesnt proceed).

However, when this activity is built as a seperate app by itself, it runs everything correctly. Only when i import it into another application, it fails to reach onActivityResult.

This is my code:

```
public class PickPhotoActivity extends Activity {
Button btn1;
public String VALUE_NAME;
private boolean picAvailable = false;
private Uri uriSavedImage;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("UserLog","Entered PickPhotoActivity");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_photo);
    Log.d("UserLog","Inflated view");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    VALUE_NAME = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    Log.d("Userlog", "Got intent, data " + VALUE_NAME);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_takePhoto);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AppImages");
               imagesFolder.mkdirs();
               String filename = VALUE_NAME + ".jpg";
               File image = new File(imagesFolder, filename);
               uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
               Log.d("UserLog", "Photo saved as: " + uriSavedImage);
               imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
               startActivityForResult(imageIntent,100);
          }
        });
    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chooseExisting);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 2);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("UserLog","Result code" + Integer.toString(requestCode));
    if(requestCode==100){
        Log.d("UserLog","Getting Image By:Take New");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        imageView.setImageURI(uriSavedImage);
        picAvailable=true;
    }else if(requestCode==2){
        Log.d("UserLog","Getting Image By:Choose Existing");
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        picAvailable=true;
    }
}
```

}

I have Log.d's placed in various places in my code. Output (consisting of logs) is

```
Entered PickPhotoActivity
Inflated view
Got intent, data
Photo saved as: file///mnt/sdcard/AppImages/.jpg
```

Stops here. Doesn't output resultcode as it should.
In a side note, the intent extra data is always empty.
If this helps, this activity itself was called with a startActivityForResult from another activity.

Comment: Does the file actually get created?  Your log shows a filename of ".jpg".  Check to see if /mnt/sdcard/AppImages/.jpg exists.

Comment: I was only printing the file path. It might not be actually saved.

Comment: I suspect that the path you are giving it doesn't exist or isn't writeable and that may be the reason you don't get the callback.